# How to re-architect slow web pages pulling lots of data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure, architecture

I run an ASP.NET (C#) Web Forms ecommerce website hosted in Azure as an auto scale-out WebApp, using an AzureSQL database. Each of the 300k product pages displays a significant amount of data that's pulled from the database. Retrieving the necessary data requires running several relatively large, complex queries referencing several relational tables each (i.e., lots of joins). I cannot show any less data on each page as it's a business requirement and beyond my control. I've added several SQL indexes, both manually and using recommendations made by Azure, but the queries still take too long. There are 15+ queries running for each page load. I've tried to reduce the number, but it's challenging and the resulting fewer, but more complex queries take longer to run than having a greater number of simpler queries. The product page load time is about 5 seconds, and my goal is to reduce it to under 1 second.

**I'm looking for options on how I can re-architect how we're storing/referencing our data.**

*Note: I would like to avoid solutions that dynamically load in content below the fold based on scrolling, since while this would improve load times, it does not address the underlying problem of the suboptimal way our data is being stored/referenced.*

Some options I've considered:

- Run a background service that forms a complete data set for each product page, and saves the data set in:

  - A Redis cache (would be costly).
  - A CDN (might be costly + inappropriate use of CDN).
  - A CDN, but then having each dynamically created website instance download a copy locally if one does not exist, and then referencing the local data instead of the CDN data (seems kind of dumb + would be difficult to purge local files when data sets update).
- Create some sort of flattened "warehouse" table in our SQL database where all data needed for each product page would be in a single row, and then setting up triggers or something to ensure it's updated as needed (seems sloppy + error prone + inappropriate use of relational database).
- Same thing as above, but in a new NoSQL database (possibly overkill/redundant to have two databases storing the same data).

I'm not convinced that any of my ideas are good enough to pursue, so that's what brings me here - I'm hoping someone can suggest a better option. I'm open to any solution that's compatible with ASP.NET Web Forms and Azure cloud services.

Comment: Since I don't know your exact .NET version, the possibility of upgrading your .NET version or implementing entity framework. I can't know if any of these are suitable options. But upgrading to .NET 7 could significantly improve the time LINQ queries take to execute. Making use of entity framework combined with .NET 7 might suit your needs.

Comment: Does running the queries take the long time, or is it sending that data to the client that is taking all the time? If sending data to the client side is taking ALL the time, then all the server caching in the world will not fix this issue. You not distinguished if pulling query data takes all the time, or sending data to the client takes all the time? Since if sending the data to the client takes all the time, then not even a CDN going to help you here, is it? It will be speed of the client's network, you know, the VERY poor one they have while at a coffee shop shared with 20 people.

Comment: How fast do queries run without sending ANY data to the client side? That I would determine first. Server side caching approaches thus will NEVER fix this issue anyway, will it? You have to share the number of row counts being sent to the client side. Without that information, then we can't determine if server side caching can or will even speed up this process. If bottle neck is amount of data sent to client side, then server side solutions can't help, can it? Run those queries without sending data to client - to see if they run fast, and thus you determined issue is amount of data to client.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the 'waste' is around composing the data to be displayed in your page.

You can solve it using a Cache mechanism / rather than using a complex query to grab data from multiple tables, use a Document Store based NoSQL and create documents with all the required information to be displayed. This way, rather than grabbing data from products, manufacturer, tags, etc, you will just do a quick lookup under products catalog using the product id.

e.g.

GET /products/123

```
{
   "name": "pen",
   "manufacturer": "pilot",
   "price", "123.50",
   "enabled": true,
   "availableQuantity": "12"
   . . .
}
```

I'm not sure about your budget constraints, but one thing you can do is use CosmosDB, I've read successful implementations of CosmosDB as Document Store and also as a replacement for Azure Cache for Redis.

PS: You can also try native aspnet output cache

Answer (score 1):

Caching hides a multitude of sins - some ideas:

Are the pages reasonably static? - use output caching https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/sfw2210t(v=vs.100)

Can query output be cached:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/caching-data/caching-data-in-the-architecture-cs

Consider limiting the data you return using paging: https://medium.com/@ohadinho25/linq-query-performance-improvement-guidelines-183d569b0668

Comment: I am in 100% agreement here that attempts to use some kind of caching to NOT really address the issue is a VERY BAD idea. (that's a band aid). Performance is achieved with good designs, end of story!!!!. And I am NOT one bit sold that such huge amounts of data and queries needs to occur here (despite the user pounding sand saying they HAVE to pull that amount of data? No, they do not!!!). .Paging the data is almost for sure the correct answer here. (of course we talking about using REAL sql server paging, not the built in gridview/listview pagers).

Comment: so many exclamation marks

Comment: Ok, yes, a bit too many of those ! SO don't let me edit comments (I can delete + repost). I think the point was simple, and I don't really think caching is the answer here. (it could help), but we don't know if the speed issue is slower database, or simply a boatload of too many records being sent to client side. If this is too many records, then server caching or some CDN will not fix nor help anyway.

Comment: I agree for sure. And you're right the question is about re-architecting, not quick fixing - which my suggestions definitely are